# How to create a boxplot in R from HLOC data

Tags: r, plot

Assuming a dataframe like such:

```
             ACY.Open ACY.High ACY.Low ACY.Close
2007-01-03     6.58     7.15    6.58      6.99
2007-01-04     7.24     7.35    7.15      7.35
2007-01-05     7.39     7.55    7.25      7.45
2007-01-08     7.32     7.35    7.01      7.26
2007-01-09     7.15     7.50    7.15      7.16
2007-01-10     7.30     7.45    7.21      7.24
```

How can I create a boxplot where the wiskers are the high and low values and the box top and bottom are the open and close values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those types of plots are called "candlestick charts", and you can easily plot them with `quantmod::chartSeries` (or `quantmod::chart_Series`).  FWIW, it looks like your object was created by `quantmod::getSymbols`, which means it's an xts object, not a data.frame.